# how to find the gps location using android emulator?

Tags: android

hello friends I am trying to find the current gps location of the android emulator i have used the command geo fix but if i try to retrieve the current location it is showing an exception...can anyone help me?

Comment: What exception? Do you have the proper manifest permissions?

Comment: application stopped unexpectedly...try again

Comment: i have given permission"<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS"></uses-permission>"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From imulator you can't get current location. you have to paas location yourself.try this

C:/android sdk/tools/ddms.bat

when u run this bat file u will find an emulator tab there. from this tab you can pass locations to imulator.

Comment: if this ans is satisfy you than please accept it.or vote it. and do this every time when you find anyone's ans which complete your question's purpose. so that more people can ans you.

Comment: Using DDMS section in Eclipse better and easier way.

Answer (score 2):

Go here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

Scroll down to the **Providing Mock Location Data**

Google's tutorials can be hard to understand, but they usually work great once you figure them out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't find your location with Android emulator.

But you can set your longitude and latitude manually. Using **DDMS** section in **Eclipse** better and easier way.