# getLastLocation() not working

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
TextView mLatitude;
TextView mLongitude;

final String TAG = " ";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    mLatitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mLatitude);
    mLongitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mLongitude);
    mGoogleApiClient = new      GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();


}

protected void onStart() {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
}

protected void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) throws SecurityException{


    Location mLastLocation =  LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if(mLastLocation!=null)
    {
        Log.i(TAG,"last location recieved");
        mLatitude.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
        mLongitude.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
    }
    else
    {
        Log.i(TAG,"LOCATION NOT RECEIVED");
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i(TAG,"connection suspended");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
Log.i(TAG,"connection failed");
}
```

}

Ive tried this many times but this code doesnt seem to work . Ive set all the permissions and dependancies required . Still it shows nothing on the screen.

I'M USING ANDROID EMULATOR

Thank you....

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.sairaman.lastlocation">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

 </application>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

</manifest>
```

build.app file is as follows :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.sairaman.lastlocation"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
 proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Location may not work correctly on emulator. Test on a device.

As pr [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4529411/1957401):From imulator you can't get current location. you have to pass location yourself.try this

```
C:/android sdk/tools/ddms.bat
```

when u run this bat file u will find an emulator tab there. from this tab you can pass locations to emulator.